# Facebook API: accessing a large version of the user's cover photo?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Using the Facebook Javascript SDK to make an api request for the user's cover photo is done like so:

```
FB.api('/me', {fields : 'cover'}, function(response) {
   console.log(response.cover.source) // url for the cover photo
});
```

However, the resulting image is relatively small (480x480), whereas the point of a cover photo is to fit wide elements. I'm trying to set the cover photo on my web-app to fit a `780px` container, in which the photo becomes pixelated.

Is there another method or field that can let me access the full image?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this code and it seems to work, hopefully you can manipulate it to work for you!

```
FB.api('/me?fields=cover', function(cover) {
    console.log(cover);
    document.getElementById('cover').innerHTML =
        '<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/'+cover.cover.id+'/picture?type=normal"/>'
});
```